# Javascript : replace image with drag drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to replace an image via drag and drop (of another image from a file explorer) but I don't know how. Any idea?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="drop-zone">
     <div class="insidzoneDropped">
         <img src="/images/folderdropped-icon.png" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 function handleDragEnter(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     //e.dataTransfer.setData("Id",    e.target.id+"|"+e.target.parentNode.id);
 }
 function handleDrop(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
 }
 var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
 dropZone.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
 dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete (`handleDragEnter` is not closed). Also you should describe in more details, what behaviour do you want, what happens in the case of your code and what you want to change.

Comment: @YakovL  i want to replace image but i dont know how

Comment: obviously you want to replace image on some user action. What action exactly?

Comment: @YakovL i want juste drop my  new icone in my balise `<img>`

Comment: and where do you want to drag it from before dropping?

Comment: i have my div with img  i want drop my new img in img exite  (replace)

Comment: you haven't answered where the new image is from. Do you want to drag it from a file browser? And please complete you code.

Comment: @YakovL yes ! i want to drag from a file browser

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the first two articles [here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/1/index.html). They are detailed so you have either to learn more than you need for this particular task or filter unnecessary info and try to run through and implement what you need. The first one is about using drag&drop itself and the second one will tell you how to deal with the dropped file contents (there's an example of nearly what you need, too).

An important note: if you want to drag&drop and make the image get the actual path to you local file, know that that's impossible due to security restrictions. What you can get instead is *contents* of your file (the image will be base64 encoded unless you save it to your server).